# bash: fail if script is not being run by root

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that installs some software. I want to fail as soon as possible if it is not being run by root. How can I do that?

Comment: Although I would *generally* consider this silly behavior: *Let it run until permissions fail*; the system may be setup such that the operation can be performed successfully as the current user and by forcing root this option is taken away [I've had to fix scripts that have made similar assumptions before]. On the other hand, I such much more of a case to *prevent* access or display a big fat warning if run as root.

Comment: You should try using sudo. Under linux, when you install anything you need to be root to prevent normal users installing anything that may damage the system

Comment: He wants his script to take into account that some people may forget, or be unaware of sudo (or other means of privilege escalation). Its good practice to check for run time sanity before attempting to do anything else.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-root-user-check-script.html

Comment: or, to keep it shorter check the UID env:
if [[ $UID -ne 0 ]]; then

Comment: @zlack $UID will give the original user's UID if the script is run via `sudo` while David's will consider the script as being run as root. Depending on what you're doing, David's is probably better.

Comment: As pr1001 says, UID will not work if the user is running the script using sudo, but EUID will work just fine.

Answer (score 9):

After digging around on this, the consensus seems to be that there is no need to use `id -u` in bash, as the `EUID` (effective user id) variable will be set.  As opposed to `UID`, the `EUID` will be `0` when the user is `root` or using `sudo`.  Apparently, this is around 100 times faster than running `id -u`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( EUID != 0 )); then
    echo "You must be root to do this." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30148/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-shellscript-runs-as-root-or-not

Comment: this doesn't work in the Bourne shell though. do you have any strictly POSIX compliant solutions?